# ngRepeat seems to use a random order instead of order given

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I have a json containing objects originating from my Symfony controller.

I need to loop over the objects like so

```
   <li data-ng-repeat="course in courses"></li>
```

In my app controller I do this

```
$scope.courses = {{ courses | serialize('json', serialization_context().setGroups(['identification', 'courseListing', 'portalOverview'])) | raw }};
```

The order is okay when I check the scope variable 'courses' with the ng-inspect browser plugin.

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0V53.png

But still the loop seems kinda random. The last object keeps getting placed after the 2nd child.

Any ideas? Need more info, just ask. Thanks!

Comment: what's that `$scope.courses = {{ courses | serialize('json', serialization_context().setGroups(['identification', 'courseListing', 'portalOverview'])) | raw }};`? why the curly brackets in model assignment?

Comment: I'm using twig as templating engine. But no worries, because the array 'courses' is correctly received as you can see in the screenshot provided. The order is exactly the same as the order in my php variable {{ courses | some twig filtering params }}.

Comment: Can you log the array, maybe the tool you are using orders array on it's own? I've never faced an issue with wrong order in ng-repear

Comment: I have var_dump'ed the array with PHP and the order was correct. Also console.log of the $scope.courses returns the array of objects correctly...

Comment: Okay, I wasn't using an array of objects like I thought. It was a object of objects. For some reason Angular doesn't make a big deal out of it, put doesn't handle it too well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems Angular doesn't handle objects too well when given to ng-repeat.
I transformed my object of objects to an array of objects and the objects were rendered in the correct order.

```
var arrCourses = [];
$.each($scope.courses, function(index, obj){
    arrCourses.push(obj);
});
$scope.courses = arrCourses;
```